# Editing NetCDF file to create eddies on map?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, netcdf

I have a netcdf file about Sea Level Anomalies in the global range, and I can open this file in Arcgis using "Multidimension tools - Make NetCDF Raster Layer" as a map, now I want to create some eddies as circles and also set radius of these eddies by myself on this map, but when I use "Editor - Create Features", it shows "There are no templates to show" and I cannot edit it.

Data can be downloaded on this website: ftp://ftpsedr.cls.fr/pub/oceano/AVISO/SSH/duacs/Data_Test/global/delayed-time/grids/msla/all-sat-merged/h/2008/

How can I edit this netcdf file?

Comment: I don't think you can edit a netcdf file within Arcmap. The help file talks about extracting and displaying data, nothing about editing it.

Comment: @Hornbydd I think you have just about enough in your comment to copy/paste it into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @Hornbydd](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151561/how-to-edit-netcdf-file-to-create-eddies-on-the-map#comment222460_151561):

> I don't think you can edit a netcdf file within Arcmap. The help file
>   talks about extracting and displaying data, nothing about editing it.